# ASP .NET Web API - Get plain json in POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a Web API controller that has a POST method which receives data from the request body, and all it does is send it to another web service, so deserializing the data is not necessary. How can I disable the auto deserialization done by the Web API?

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string data)
{
 //Post with http client...

}
```

The data arrives as null with this signature.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Set the request header: Content-Type text/plain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var data = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // do stuff with the content
}
```

More about the solution:
 http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Send the object as string (in its serialized format). For example

```
YourMethod([FromBody]string json)
```

Comment: It arrives as null.

Comment: Then you are not sending it properly. Make sure that you use the right headers. (ex: Content-Type: application/json). There's a tool called postman to test your APIs with

Answer (score 0):

Just read the reuest content like this:

```
public Task<IHttpActionResult> Post() {
    var str = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```