# Web API POST, get both, object and JSON plain text

Tags: json, rest, post, asp.net-web-api

Visual Studio 2019 / Net Framework 4.7.2

I'm working on a new project that uses a Rest API to receive orders from a customer using POST method.

As example, this could be the Order object:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = "";
    public string Data { get; set; } = "";
}
```

And that the Post method of my API controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Order value)
{
    if (OrderProcessed(value))
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    else
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Order cannot be processed.");
}
```

It works fine, deserialized JSON object is mapped to Order's properties.

But, in addition, I'd like to store in my DB the JSON string received within the POST command.

This question: [ASP .NET Web API - Get plain JSON in POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39270157/asp-net-web-api-get-plain-json-in-post-method) shows how to get the JSON text, but:

Is there a way to get both, Order's object and the body's text?

Comment: Why don't you just get your json string, store it in your database and map your json string to your object "manually"?

Comment: In this way it doesn't matter if the customer use XML or JSON. I simply store the received text to check it later if needed.